# Putting a curl command into a R script and capturing the output to a variable

Tags: r, curl, httr, rcurl

I would need to use the following bash command (or equivalent) into a R script. ideally, I would need to capture the output into a variable

curl -LH "Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex" https://doi.org/10.1002/cbin.11105

I checked the httr library, but I had no luck. Also, I tried  to embed the command into a system call, but I was getting a hard to parse output using the option "intern = TRUE".
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(httr)
res <- GET("https://doi.org/10.1002/cbin.11105", accept("text/bibliography; style=bibtex"))
res
# Response [https://api.crossref.org/v1/works/10.1002%2Fcbin.11105/transform]
#   Date: 2022-03-18 19:21
#   Status: 200
#   Content-Type: text/bibliography
#   Size: 475 B
#  @article{2019, title={Silencing of MEG3 inhibited ox-LDL-induced inflammation and apoptosis in macrophages via ...
```

(Note the `Status: 200` to ensure it was successful.)

```r
content(res)
# No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
# [1] " @article{2019, title={Silencing of MEG3 inhibited ox-LDL-induced inflammation and apoptosis in macrophages via modulation of the MEG3/miR-204/CDKN2A regulatory axis}, volume={43}, ISSN={1095-8355}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cbin.11105}, DOI={10.1002/cbin.11105}, number={4}, journal={Cell Biology International}, publisher={Wiley}, author={Yan, Long and Liu, Zhanchuan and Yin, Haoyuan and Guo, Zhenjie and Luo, Qi}, year={2019}, month={Feb}, pages={409?420} }\n"
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked great! One last thing if you don't mind. Do you know how to extract from the res variable the  content that comes out from the shell command and put it in a standalone variable? I mean this text:  @article{2019, title={Silencing of MEG3 inhibited ox‐LDL‐induced inflammation and apoptosis in macrophages via modulation of the MEG3/miR‐204/CDKN2A regulatory axis}, volume={43}, ISSN={1095-8355}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cbin.11105}, DOI={10.1002/cbin.11105}, number={4}, journal={Cell Biology International}, publisher={Wiley}, author={Yan, Long and Liu, etc....

Comment: Oh, I figured it : a<- content (res)